# How to split column names and it's value to different columns instead of all in one (Pandas)

Tags: python, database, pandas, csv

I'm using pandas and I'm trying to read a `csv` that looks like the following:

[image: excel sheet example:]

And I'm trying to separate the column names and its values. So, my desirable end results is: `df.head()`

```
A       B       C        D

12     32      43       23
33     42      32       44
11     43      65       23
55     66      77       88
```

I have tried using both
`df = pd.read_csv("test.csv",sep=",")` and `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv",delimiter=",")` when reading the `csv` file but it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the file you try to parse as text into your question (inside code formatting) - or code to create the file in question. This should be a simple case of `pd.read_csv(.., sep=",")`.

Comment: seems all your data is in column A. Why not read it in: ``pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['A'])``. Then split column A into individual columns : ``df.A.str.split(",", expand=True)``

Comment: @sammywemmy I have tried what you've suggested, but why does it delete the column names and replace it with values from 1 to n instead of the actual column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

I created sample data like yours:

[image]

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('stack.csv')
df[['A','B','C','D']] = df['A,B,C,D'].str.split(',',expand=True)

#output:
#   A,B,C,D A   B   C   D
#0  1,2,3,4 1   2   3   4
#1  5,6,7,8 5   6   7   8
#2  9,10,11,12  9   10  11  12

del df['A,B,C,D'] #deleting the first column(A,B,C,D) as you don't need
df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I just have to mention that the sample data you created is not exactly like his.
His looks like that:
a, b, c, d
1,2,3,4,,,
5,6,7,8,,,
etc..

Answer (score 1):

Delimiter and sep attributes of read_csv function works at the tabular level, as the delimiter by which u want to split is present with in a cell it doesnt apply on that.
Instead further processing can be done. This code below does well.

```
    df=pd.read_csv("nba_logreg.csv")
    df2= df['a,b,c,d'].str.split(',')
    df2.columns=df.columns.str.split(',')[0]
    df2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an exact same csv file. With the command: `pd.read_csv ("test.csv")`, it works for me the way you want it to. What exactly does not work for you or what kind of error do you get?

Comment: This should be a comment - not an answer

Comment: @gtomer I'm new to Stackoverflow, therefore I can't comment on posts yet, I still wanted to help.

Comment: I see. Hope you will gain experience here quickly :-)